# Qt & SqlAlchemy - Qtableview

Tags: python, qt, sqlalchemy, pyside, qtableview

Ok - taking baby steps toward a very simple MVC app using pyside and sqlalchemy... such baby steps that I've got stuck on step #1!

I want to populate a QTableView with data. Should I be using QSqlTableModel or QStandardItemModel or QAbstractItemModel... or something else.  If using QSqlTableModel, can I just 'setTable' (and, if so, how).

If anybody can point me in the direction of a decent tutorial or good qt/sqlalchemy example I would be eternally grateful.

I understand that this may be a bit basic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you start with a list to understand how the model-view implementation actually works first. Inherit your custom model from QAbstractListModel and you just need to implement the methods data and rowCount for it to work.

Here is a good tutorial explaining everything https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/modelview-architecture/

And if you want something for reference, I've found this really old gist implementing an sqlalchemy model for a tableview. It's on pyqt4 and possible would not work anymore but it should help guide you in the right direction.
https://gist.github.com/harvimt/4699169

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to take a look for Camelot project.

http://www.python-camelot.com/index.html

Maybe you can get some ideas from there.

Comment: Have looked at Camelot and don't really want to add yet another complication.  Thanks though.